# How do I save a command output to a variable, and how do I use that variable as command parameter in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, file, variables

I'd like to replace a word inside a `.cfg` file with the name of the current user.

I know `$env:username` outputs the current user.

This is what I got:

```
(Get-Content -path path\example.cfg -Raw) -replace 'TEST','current_user' | Set-Content path\example.cfg
```

I'm trying to replace the word "TEST" with the current user.

Answer (score 2):

Just replace your literal string `'current_user'` with `$env:username` and you're good to go :)

```
(Get-Content -path path\example.cfg -Raw) -replace 'TEST',$env:username | Set-Content path\example.cfg
```

Note that `-replace` is a regex operator, so we can even qualify the word we're looking for:

```
(Get-Content -path path\example.cfg -Raw) -replace '\bTEST\b',$env:username | Set-Content path\example.cfg
```

`\b` means "word boundary" in regex, and will help you avoid partially replacing `TEST` in words like "HOTTEST" or "TESTICULAR"